# CentOS 6.x e-mail routing wierdness

Tags: centos, sendmail

I have a CentOS server configured to accept e-mail and redirect to another server. It's using the Sendmail virtusertable to perform the redirects.

I don't know how long this has been happening but one of my users has brought to my attention that they have been getting e-mail for two of the other users in their inbox.

When I look at /var/log/maillog I can see that every single e-mail that comes in addressed singularly to user1, user2 or user3 are being routed to "to=<user1@domain>,<user2@domain>,<user3@domain>".

On the destination server, the header only shows to unmodified TO field, eg:

1. e-mail comes in to user1@domain on server #1
2. e-mail is forwarded to user1, 2, & 3 on server #2
3. e-mail arrives in all three mailboxes on server #2 but the e-mail still says it was only for user1 in all copies.

I have almost twenty+ users on this system and this is only happening between these three.

The problem is absolutely happening someplace on server #1 though and I'm seriously at my wits end on this and any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Logs and configuration would help.

Comment: What logs, what configs? I've looked over everything in /ect/mail and I have no rules of any kind that would explain this. What I'm really trying to ask here is what configs can I look at to try and locate a behavior like this.

Comment: Logs: the relevant log lines for the emails on both servers. Config: the virtusertable would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: Ok, let me see what I can do as I'm going to have to scrub identifying info.

BTW, I just did a test  "/usr/sbin/sendmail -v user2@domain" and in this case the e-mail only showed up at user2's mailbox. If I try e-mailing them from an external server, it goes to all three. I'm not sure if that helps thinking about where in the process I might check.

Comment: Try `/usr/sbin/sendmail -bv user1@domain` for all three addresses. Do you use any milters or "sandwich" spam filtering?

Comment: "the header only shows to unmodified TO field". That's completely normal. The `To:` header has nothing to do with envelope recipient.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip, I tried that early on and those tests send the e-mail directly to the recipient only on all 3 users, and the logs show it only going to them. This is happening specifically with inbound e-mail only with user1, and the /var/log/maillog shows any mail that comes into them being forwarded onto the imap server addressed like I posted above regardless to who it was really sent to. I did pin this behavior down to starting sometime after January this year and I'm trying to see if I can pin it down even better. No spam filters, etc... at this time.